# How to parse a compact JSON Array in android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON Array like this:

[4, 3, 2, 1,...]

It is a simple array, and I am not able to find a single tutorial that tells me how to parse this array. I want to assign each element to a string Array that I have created like:

```
String H[];
```

I always get stuck when it comes to returning a value from a method, I get confused. For Example:
Within the Oncreate() method, after initializing all variables I type:

```
solarData();
//displaying only one value from the String Array H[];
TextView.setText(H[0]);


public JSONArray solarData() throws JSONException{

//After getting response from HttpClient and getting result
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<jArray,length();i++){
String H[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();    
}
return jArray;
}
```

Now what is it returning? I want it to return the String Array. So that I can display any value I want from the String Array to which I am storing these values.

Comment: declerate your "String H[i]" BEFORE your loop. It can't work if you handle it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JSONArray documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), you can see there is a constructor that takes a valid JSON string and does all of the parsing work for you.  You seem to have identified this already.

The problem here is that in each iteration of your for loop, you are attempting to create a new String array.  You should initialize your array before the loop, and then populate its contents after initializing it.  Something like this should work for you:

```
public JSONArray solarData() throws JSONException{

  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  // consider renaming H to something meaningful (e.g. planetList)
  String H[] = new String[jArray.length()];
  for (int i=0; i < jArray,length() ;i++) {
    H[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();    
  }
  return jArray;
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it